# R/Plyr function for outputting column value based on the maximum value in another column, by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with three columns (Mouse, Day, vol). I am trying to use dplyr to create a new dataframe to extract the last "Day"  value for each mouse and the corresponding "vol" for that mouse. I am able to use the max function to get the right "Day" but am having trouble grabbing the matching "vol". Any help is appreciated. Below is my dataframe dput and the code I am trying to assemble.

```
final_meas <- ddply(df, "Mouse", summarise,
               final_day = max(Day),
               final_vol = 
)
```

If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Data frame dput()

```
structure(list(Mouse = c("CF1", "CF2", "CG1", "CG2", "CG3", "CO1", 
"CO2", "CU1", "CY1", "CF1", "CF2", "CG1", "CG2", "CG3", "CO1", 
"CO2", "CU1", "CY1", "CF1", "CF2", "CG1", "CG2", "CG3", "CO1", 
"CO2", "CU1", "CY1", "CF1", "CF2", "CG1", "CG2", "CG3", "CO1", 
"CO2", "CF2", "CG1", "CG2", "CG3", "CO1", "CF2", "CG1", "CG2", 
"CG3", "CO1", "CF2", "CG1", "CG2", "CG3", "CO1", "CF2", "CG1", 
"CG2", "CG3", "CO1", "CF2", "CG1", "CG2", "CG3", "CO1", "CF2", 
"CG1", "CG2", "CG3", "CO1"), Day = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38), vol = c(45.9675, 36.1712655, 
87.777976, 14.29754, 14.2842745, 22.989735, 19.3821875, 56.216752, 
71.251488, 0.5, 44.6299425, 119.070536, 26.82875, 21.999132, 
71.801216, 0.5, 255.874619, 137.720968, 0.5, 21.5552, 115.16616, 
33.132848, 17.619264, 51.185368, 0.5, 212.1728, 340.5686, 0, 
0.5, 75.154122, 76.0952875, 0.5, 107.208528, 0, 0.5, 63.5839875, 
233.4784, 0.5, 74.6727445, 0.5, 55.7932375, 361.3029455, 0, 88.297668, 
0.5, 38.0849105, 228.4934, 0.5, 136.778328, 0.5, 0.5, 186.7279545, 
0.5, 178.4032435, 0.5, 0, 186.7279545, 0.5, 89.4645, 0.5, 0, 
186.7279545, 0.5, 169.296399)), row.names = c(NA, -64L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

df_example %>% 
  group_by(Mouse) %>% 
  mutate(max_day = max(Day),
         max_vol = if_else(Day == max(Day),vol,NA_real_)) %>% 
  fill(max_vol,.direction = "downup")
```

Comment: Thank you, that gets me the information I want and I can subset it out to a new dataframe, but if possible would like to skip that step and directly output it in a new dataframe with just mouse, max_day, and max_vol.

Comment: Just select the columns you want